# how to apply sorting in ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I have one angularjs project in which I am using ui-grid.

As you can see in my code, I have some attribute in cell-template. I have to perform sorting based on "**rating-percentage**".

So I am trying to write a sorting algorithm which required row.entity property.

My question is that how can I add rating percentage in row.entity.

What is the right way to perform sorting using "rating-percentage"?

Below is my code:

```
 define([
    'angular'
  ], function (angular) {

    function SelectToolController($scope, $timeout, $filter) {
      var vm = this,
      _gridApi,
      _cellTemplate,
      _columnDefs,
      _starRatingTemplate,
      _starRatingColumn;

 _starRatingTemplate =[
       '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ">',
          '<div class="opr-star-rating" >',
            '<opr-star-rating rating-percentage="{{rowRenderIndex}}"',
              'total-count="23"',
              'suffix-display="true"',
              'rating-display="true"',
              'count-display="22">',
            '</opr-star-rating>',
          '</div>',
          '</div>'
      ].join('');

_starRatingColumn = {
          name: 'starRating',
          cellTemplate: _starRatingTemplate,
          displayName: 'Rating',
          enableFiltering: false,
          enableSorting: true,
          cellClass: 'star-column',
          enableHiding: false,
          enableRowSelection: true,
        }
 _columnDefs.push(_starRatingColumn);

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your custom sorting function then link this function to column definition.

```
 $scope.sortFun=function(a, b) { 
   ///.... your logic
 }

_starRatingColumn = {
      name: 'starRating',
      cellTemplate: _starRatingTemplate,
      displayName: 'Rating',
      enableFiltering: false,
      enableSorting: true,
      cellClass: 'star-column',
      enableHiding: false,
      enableRowSelection: true,
      'sortingAlgorithm': $scope.sortFun
    }
```

change your template.

```
'<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ">',
      '<div class="opr-star-rating" ng-class="col.colIndex() >',
        '<opr-star-rating rating-percentage="{{row.entity}}"',
          'total-count="23"',
          'suffix-display="true"',
          'rating-display="true"',
          'count-display="22">',
        '</opr-star-rating>',
      '</div>',
      '</div>'
```

Comment: actually, what I am not able to understand is, how to get the value of ratingPercentage in sorting function?

Comment: change cell template  according to this.

Comment: It is not recognizing col property itself

Comment: you can also use **row.entity**. you  rating-percentage attribute will receive complete object of array result

Comment: Yes I am trying with row.entity only. Problem is that it is not getting any of attribute mentioned in cellTemplate in row.entity. I am trying to get rating-percentage in row.entity. But no luck!

Comment: It may be issue because you are using directive into another directive.
Try to replace opr-star-rating with div. check whether you are receive entity or not.